# Permute array to order of selection in Josephus problem

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, pointers

How can we write code to permute an array to the order of selection in the [Josephus problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem)?

Given a sequence of items (such as an array of `char *`) and a skip distance *d*, we skip *d* items from the start, take that item to be the first in the output sequence, then skip *d* further items, take the resulting item to be the second in the output, and continue in this way. When we reach the end of the sequence, we wrap to the beginning, continuing to count. Only items remaining in the array are counted for the skip distance; removed items no longer count.

For example, given:

```
char *arr[] = {"first", "second", "third", "fourth"};
skip=6;
```

we would count 6 items: `"first"`, `"second"`, `"third"`, `"fourth"`, (wrapping around) `"first"`, `"second"`. So `"second"` becomes the first output item. Then we count six again: `"third"`, `"fourth"`, `"first"`, `"third"`, `"fourth"`, `"first"`, and we take `"first"` as the next output element. The we count six again: `"third"`, `"fourth"`, `"third"`, `"fourth"`, `"third"`, `"fourth"`, and we take `"fourth"` as the third output element. Counting six again repeats `"third"` six times, and `"third"` becomes the last output element.

So the result is `"second"`, `"first"`, `"fourth"`, `"third"`.

So far I have managed to write this:

```
void rroulette(char* arr,int skip)
{
    if(skip>LENGTH)
    {
        skip=skip%LENGTH;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<=LENGTH;i++)//allowing index to pass the array len limit so it'll go back to 0
    {
        int counter=skip;
        if(i==LENGTH)//array index is at the (final+1) spot so it goes back to 0
            i=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the sorting logic?

Comment: What is a “skip” or “skip size”? You will need to explain the rules and terms.

Comment: I assume the idea is to effectively rotate each string N positions so you'd end up comparing something like `irstf, second, hirdt, fourth`. If that's true then neither zero or one based indexing seems to give the post-sort order you've shown. *shrug*

Comment: All you've done is repeat what's in your question. For your example with those 4 strings can you detail exactly the process required to sort them in the order you've said is correct? Doesn't have to be code, show us how you'd solve it with pen and paper.

Comment: I'll try to explain it extensively-
given-
`char *arr[]={"first","second","third","fourth"}
skip=6;`

`skip=skip%len` is 2, thats the normal skip size compared to the length of the array

so, as we begin sorting the array, `arr[0]` is num 1, `arr[1]` is num 2, so arr[1] is the first element in the sorted array, then, `arr[2]` is the new number 1 in our skip count, cuz `arr[3]` is number 2 on skip, `arr[3]` becomes the second element in the sorted array, then the initial index goes back to 0, but when it gets to an element it alrdy sorted, index grows by one and the skipping continues

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to *permute* an array (rearrange or reorder its elements) in a way determined by the skip value, not to *sort* it (rearrange the elements in an order determined by their values). Further, it sounds like the first step is to “skip” through the array a distance of `skip` elements (rotating around the end of the array), taking each element landed on, until the skipping loops back to its starting point. It is not clear what to do after that though. Are the remaining elements treated as a new array, pushed together to fill the gaps left by taking the other elements,…

Comment: … and then skipped through again? Give more examples, and show the steps in more detail. Edit the information into the question; do not post it as a comment.

Comment: This is the order of selection used in the [Josephus problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem).

Comment: I have rewritten the post to describe the Josephus selection method. However, are you sure the skip distance is reduced modulo the list length before doing any counting? That affects how the selection proceeds. I suspect you reduced it as an early optimization. What does the original problem you are working on say about this? I rewrote the post assuming the distance is counted completely, with wrapping, not reduced first. If that is not the original intent, I can rewrite it to reduce the skip distance first. We can also roll back the post to a version prior to my edit.

Comment: Is the requirement of the assignment that the results be returned in the same array they are given in or that no new arrays be created at all?

Comment: Voted to close because OP apparently abandoned the question and has not answered requests for clarification.

Comment: @EricPostpischil apologizes for disappearing, eventually I was able to solve this, after a long time though.

Thank you for your assistance!